# Connecting to EFS from Elastic Beanstalk with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mkdir, amazon-efs

As usual, the simpler the operation the more AWS documentation confounds me. I want to use PHP to write and read files stored on EFS. I am experienced with using the AWS PHP library, I just need the correct code to facilitate communication. Here's my set up:

- 1 EFS File System on my default VPC.
- 1 Elasticbeanstalk environment with the "storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config" added to the .ebextensions directory of the latest application code and initialized without error (which makes me think it is connecting). The security group for the EB is added to the EFS security group. The AWS PHP SDK also exists with the application
- 1 PHP File in the application

Now in the file I normally connect to other services in this manner:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
$options = [
    'region'            => 'us-east-1',
    'version'           => '2006-03-01',
    'signature_version' => 'v4',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'key#',
        'secret' => 'secret#'
    ] 
];
$GLOBALS['s3Client'] = new S3Client($options);
$writeFile = $GLOBALS['s3Client']->putObject(array(...
```

I presume this should be the same for EFS. As a first guess, I tried:

```
$efsOptions = [
    'region'            => 'us-east-1',
    'version'           => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'key#',
        'secret' => 'secret#'
    ] 
];
use Aws\Efs\EfsClient;
$efsClient = new EfsClient($efsOptions);
$result = $efsClient->describeFileSystems(array(
    'FileSystemId' => 'fs-#'
));
```

But get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Efs\Exception\EfsException' with message 'Error executing "DescribeFileSystems" on "https://elasticfilesystem.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-02-01/file-systems?FileSystemId=f#"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET https://elasticfilesystem.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-02-01/file-systems?FileSystemId=f#` resulted in a `403 Forbidden`
```

So what's the right way to do this? (Sudo Code):

```
use Aws\efs\EfsClient;
$options = [
    'What keys need to be here' => 'paramter',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'key#',
        'secret' => 'sevret#'
    ] 
];
$efsClient = new EfsClient($options);
$dir = "/test/";
$makeDir = $efsClient -> mkdir($dir);
$scanDir = $efsClient -> scandir($dir);
print_r($scanDir);
**/test/
```

I never use console or connect to the server to install packages so please constrain this to answers that allow me to do everything in the PHP file or a limited "one time" console configuration. The point of this is I need the PHP script to create and read files on EFS and to share those with other EB environments. AWS documentation I've reviewed or used so far:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html
https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Efs.EfsClient.html

Comment: Why not just mount the EFS as a share on your EC2 instance your code is running on. Then the EFS is just a regular path that your PHP app can write to. That is what we do on our Elastic Beanstalk web servers for persisting user file uploads, etc.

Comment: Yes, that could work as well. Do you have any example code for how you're accomplishing the connection? It would be great to use PHP's native file commands.

Comment: I answered below with a small example.

Comment: @mrunion thank you sir .. I'll give this a shot today and follow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just mount the EFS as a share on your EC2 instance your code is running on. Then the EFS is just a regular path that your PHP app can write to. That is what we do on our Elastic Beanstalk web servers for persisting user file uploads, etc.

You have to set up the connection from the EB/EC2 instance using the AWS EBExtensions mechanism when the code is deployed. An example configuration snippet for doing that is:

```
# config.yml file:

files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/my_config_job.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      # Load the EFS path from the EB environment settings
      # (The variables are set in the "Configuration" section in the AWS
      # Console under the "Environment properties" area. That area takes
      # Name and Value pairs, so in our example below, the value
      # "WHERE_TO_MOUNT_EFS" is the Name of the variable, and it contains
      # a path on the EC2, for example "/efs". That would mount the EFS
      # volume at the path /efs on the filesystem.
      WHERE_TO_MOUNT_EFS=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k WHERE_TO_MOUNT_EFS)

      # This is the actual AWS EFS volume name that has been set up
      EFS_VOLUME_NAME=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k EFS_VOLUME_NAME)

      # Now create the path for the mount on the filesystem (again, in 
      # our example "/efs" as specified in the WHERE_TO_MOUNT_EFS variable)
      mkdir ${WHERE_TO_MOUNT_EFS}

      # Now actually mount the EFS to the "/efs" folder created above
      mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1 ${EFS_VOLUME_NAME}-$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone).mydomain.com:/ ${WHERE_TO_MOUNT_EFS}
```

This is just a sample, of course.

The "curl" commands are used to query information AWS provides at the special IP 169.254.169.154. Your domain and path would be different.

Also, this is a Bash script that runs on Linux. If you are using Windows on your EB you will have to adapt this process.

Finally, after the mount above, in our scripts we actually go on to create a symlink from a subfolder of our website to the EFS folder that was attached. We also manage the permissions with Bash commands that assign the "webapp" user the permissions it needs. Those steps are optional of course.

Now PHP will just see that folder as a path on the filesystem, but in reality it is on your EFS share. When EB environment(s) get rebuilt, this script is automatically re-ran and the EFS is reattached, so the data appears to be persistent to the app on the EC2.

I hope this helps

Comment: Hey @mrunion - Again, thank you so much for this .. just got back from traveling and was able to test it. One clarification, "mydomain.com" should be the URL of the EB application correct? I was able to follow all of your instructions which happened without error. When I run PHP's mkdir it get "Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied" as user "ec2-user". Does that sound like the permissions issue your go on the describe in the optional section? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, use your domain. As for the PHP error, yes your assumption appears to be correct -- at least partially. In our case the web applications run as the user "webapp" not "ec2-user". You could add another piece of code to the sample script above right after the "mkdir...WHERE_TO_MOUNT_EFS.." part that changes the mount point permissions so the "webapp" user can write there. At my office we use only one EFS and in each app's script above we have an additional step after the "mount" that creates a subfolder on the EFS for that specific app, then grants the "webapp" user/group proper access.

Comment: Yep, webapp worked perfectly. Thank you very much for taking the time to help out .. this was a huge help.

Comment: what if i want to mount my efs to lets say /var/www/html/uploads folder...I tried creating my mount point as /var/www/html/uploads, but after environment creation the efs is getting mounted to /var/app/current.old/uploads... don't understand why.